# Trying to invoke a method called addAccount for a bank application but it keeps giving me .class is expected error

Tags: java

This has been giving me error when I try to invoke the `addAccount` method saying .class is expected on the line where I try to invoke it.
I am trying to do an assignment whereby I am supposed to create a method called `addAccount` that accepts two parameters; `accountName` and `accountBalance` and put the parameters into an `accountArray`

```
import java.util.*;
public class bank
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        int accountNo = 0;
        double accountBal = 0;
        int[] accountNoArray = new int[20];
        int[] accountBalArray = new int[20];
        displayMenu();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Your Choice: ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1)
        {
        System.out.print("Please Enter NRIC number: ");
        accountNo = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Account Balance: ");
        accountBal = sc.nextInt();
        }
        public static void displayMenu()
        {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add an account");
        System.out.println("2.Search an account with the given account number");
        System.out.println("3.Display accounts below the given balance");
        System.out.println("4.Exit");
        }
        public static void addAccount(int accountNo,double accountBal)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to invoke the method.

Comment: you should not declare all the functions as static. Declare the functions as normal functions, instantiate an object of the class in main and then access the functions from that object..

Comment: Please consider using an IDE such as Eclipse, so that you can catch these compiler errors.

Comment: OMG! r u from SIM? taking java ICT131? haha long time since i did this!!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing curly bracket before the definition of the displayMenu method. The following version is syntactically correct:

```
public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        int accountNo = 0;
        double accountBal = 0;
        int[] accountNoArray = new int[20];
        int[] accountBalArray = new int[20];
        displayMenu();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Your Choice: ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter NRIC number: ");
            accountNo = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please Enter Account Balance: ");
            accountBal = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add an account");
        System.out.println("2.Search an account with the given account number");
        System.out.println("3.Display accounts below the given balance");
        System.out.println("4.Exit");
    }

    public static void addAccount(int accountNo, double accountBal) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify parameter type while calling a method.

Here is an error:

```
case 1 : addAccount(int accountNo,double accountBal);
```

It must be:

```
case 1 : addAccount(accountNo,accountBal); break;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! But now i am trying to input array into addAccount so i can place the user inputted account number and account balance inside the array but i am getting " method addaccount cannot be applied to given types.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared it static so you need to add the class name before the call

```
bank.addAccount(int accountNo,double accountBal);
```

and instead of the types decleration you have to call it with parameters.

```
bank.addAccount(accountNo,accountBal);
```

Comment: since the static method is called from within the same class as it is declared, there is no need to specify the class name for the call

Comment: Ok Thanks! But now i am trying to input array into addAccount so i can place the user inputted account number and account balance inside the array but i am getting " method addaccount cannot be applied to given types.