# Java .class is expected

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to invoke a method called addAccount for a bank application but it keeps giving me .class is expected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016317/trying-to-invoke-a-method-called-addaccount-for-a-bank-application-but-it-keeps)

I am trying to do a school assignment for a bank application. It's supposed to have addAccount method and takes in 2 parameters from 2 arrays; accountNumber and accountBalance respectively. I am trying to input accountNoArray into the addAccount method but when i do that and invoke it, it says .class is expected error

```
import java.util.*;
public class bank
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0;
    int accountNo = 0;
    double accountBal = 0;
    int[] accountNoArray = new int[20];
    double[] accountBalArray = new double[20];
    displayMenu();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Your Choice: ");
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 : addAccount(accountNo,accountBal,sc); break;
    }
}

public static void displayMenu()
{
    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Add an account");
    System.out.println("2.Search an account with the given account number");
    System.out.println("3.Display accounts below the given balance");
    System.out.println("4.Exit");
}   

public static void addAccount(int accountNo,double accountBal,Scanner sc)
{
    System.out.print("Please Enter NRIC Number: ");
    accountNo = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Account Balance: ");
    accountBal = sc.nextInt();
}
}
```

Comment: Is this the same question you recently asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016317/trying-to-invoke-a-method-called-addaccount-for-a-bank-application-but-it-keeps